# django-modeltranslation : how to know if the value is defined in a given language?

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

I am using [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) for translation of my content.

If the value of a translated field is not set for a language then it automatically takes the value of the default language.

However, is there a way to know if value for a given language has been set?

If for example `title_fr` is not set, `obj.title_fr` will return the value of `obj.title`. 
How to know if the french version has been defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access original field value with `instance.__dict__['title_fr']`.

However, you probably want to customize `fallback_values` option:

https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#fallback-values

Comment: The getattr(instance, 'title_fr') will also work! In fact, i had this problem because the translated field is a AutoSlugField (django_extensions)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on fallback-values but I am not sure it corresponds to this need. It seems that it can be used to get the default value of a translated field

Comment: ``fallback_values = {'title': None}`` would make modeltranslation to  return french title or None for ``title`` with french lang. This may be what you want. I did not try but think it should work.